# Create subscription service to deliver reports on mail

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, .net

I have a question related to creating the subscriptions. I have to create a model for delivering the reports to users on mail . The reports which I create are web based reports that is the reports are created using html control (like table,tr,td etc..) . Now the user wants to schedule these reports so that they can get the reports every morning in there mail box.

can anyone please help me in getting some direction for doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are already creating the reports on the web, just make a script to send an email to the user containing a link to website your reports are on.

If by chance `mail` doesn't mean `email`, then print out a page with the text link to your web reports, but add a long querystring at the end with a mix of uppercase, lowercase, and numeric digits.  Bonus points if you can convince them they have to type it in exactly.  It won't take very long for them to decide just to go to the original webpage you created.

Comment: actually the mails will be send to the user on daily/weekly/monthly/yearly basis as per the user requirement. In short I have to make a subscription like Sql server reporting services subscription.